# Find adjacent members

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I have to find if two members of a list are adjacent. The restriction is to use the `append/3` predicate. So far I've done the below, it works if it's true, otherwise I get no answer, it's like it runs eternally.

```
adjacent(X,Y,L):-
   append(L1,[X,Y],T1),append(T1,T2,L).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see that your program will loop, it suffices to consider the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
    adjacent(X,Y,L):-
       append(L1,[X,Y],T1), false,
       append(T1,T2,L).
```

If this program will loop, then the original program will loop too. It might succeed, but still it will loop.

In your first goal both `L1` and `T1` are uninstantiated variables - that's easy to see, because they are not used anywhere else in this fragment. As a consequence, this program will *always* loop, no matter what `X`, `Y` or `L` might be. To fix this, you have to modify something in the visible part.

One possibility would be to exchange the two goals. But there is an even easier way out:

```
adjacent(X,Y,L) :-
   append(_,[X,Y|_],L)
```

Note however, that this does not ensure that `L` is really a well formed list. In fact, `adjacent(1,2,[1,2|nonlist])` succeeds. In case it should be a list:

```
adjacent(X,Y,L) :-
   append(_,[X,Y|R],L),
   append(R,[],R).
```

See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best answer, but you can also try:

```
adjacent(X,Y,Zs):- append(As,[X,Y|Ys],Zs).
```

For example:

```
3 ?- adjacent(1,2,[1,2,3]).
true .
1 ?- adjacent(1,3,[1,2,3]).
false.
```

Comment: That's the same as the first solution @false suggested in his answer (he used `_` for the singleton variables).