# DCG and inversion of a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to count the numer of *inversions* in a list. A predicate `inversion(+L,-N)` unifies `N` to the number of inversions in that list. A *inversion* is defined as `X > Y` and `X` appears before `Y` in the list (unless `X` or `Y` is `0`). For example:

```
?- inversions([1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7,8],N).
N = 0.

?- inversions([1,2,3,0,4,6,8,5,7],N).
N = 3.
```

*For what I'm using this for, the list will always have exacly 9 elements, and always containing the numbers `0-8` uniquely.*

I'm quite new to Prolog and I'm trying to do this as concise and as elegant as possible; It seems like [DCG](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG) will probably help a lot. I read into the official definition and some tutorial sites, but still don't quit understand what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *...and `X` appears before `Y` in the list...* Is that *immediately* after, or at any point after?

Comment: This is really a nice clpfd-example. I will put a bounty for a clpfd-solution

Comment: @lurker, any point before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such application-specific constraints can often be built using *reified constraints* (constraints whose truth value is reflected into a 0/1 variable). This leads to a relatively natural formulation, where B is 1 iff the condition you want to count is satisfied:

```
:- lib(ic).

inversions(Xs, N) :-
    ( fromto(Xs, [X|Ys], Ys, [_]), foreach(NX,NXs) do
        ( foreach(Y,Ys), param(X), foreach(B,Bs) do
            B #= (X#\=0 and Y#\=0 and X#>Y)
        ),
        NX #= sum(Bs)       % number of Ys that are smaller than X
    ),
    N #= sum(NXs).
```

This code is for [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org).

Comment: `inversions(Xs, 1).` fails, yet `Xs = [2,1,0], inversions(Xs, 1).` succeeds using 6.2development #21. Is there a better version?

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution that doesn't leave choice points using `if_/3`:

```
inversions([],0).
inversions([H|T], N):-
   if_( H = 0, 
        inversions(T,N),
        ( find_inv(T,H,N1),inversions(T, N2), N #= N1+N2 )
      ).

find_inv([],_,0).
find_inv([H1|T],H,N1):-
   if_( H1=0,
        find_inv(T,H,N1),
        if_( H#>H1, 
             (find_inv(T,H,N2),N1 #= N2+1),
             find_inv(T,H,N1) 
           )
       ).

#>(X, Y, T) :-
   (  integer(X),
      integer(Y)
   -> ( X > Y
      -> T = true
      ;  T = false
      )
   ;  X #> Y,
      T = true
   ;  X #=< Y,
      T = false
   ).
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not so sure a DCG would be helpful here. Although we're processing a sequence, there's a lot of examination of the entire list at each point when looking at each element.

Here's a CLPFD approach which implements the "naive" algorithm for inversions, so it's transparent and simple, but not as efficient as it could be (it's *O*(n^2)). There's a more efficient algorithm (*O*(n log n)) involving a [divide and conquer](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~rlaz/algorithms20082/slides/RankDistance.pdf) approach, which I show further below.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

inversions(L, C) :-
    L ins 0..9,
    all_distinct(L),
    count_inv(L, C).

% Count inversions    
count_inv([], 0).
count_inv([X|T], C) :-
    count_inv(X, T, C1),     % Count inversions for current element
    C #= C1 + C2,            % Add inversion count for the rest of the list
    count_inv(T, C2).        % Count inversions for the rest of the list

count_inv(_, [], 0).
count_inv(X, [Y|T], C) :-
    (   X #> Y, X #> 0, Y #> 0
    ->  C #= C1 + 1,         % Valid inversion, count it
        count_inv(X, T, C1)
    ;   count_inv(X, T, C)
    ).

?- inversions([1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7,8],N).
N = 0 ;
false.

?- inversions([1,2,3,0,4,6,8,5,7],N).
N = 3 ;
false.

?-  inversions([0,2,X],1).
X = 1 ;
false.
```

It does leave a choice point, as you can see, which I haven't sorted out yet.

---

Here's the *O*(n log n) solution, which is using the sort/merge algorithm.

```
inversion([], [], 0).
inversion([X], [X], 0).
inversion([HU1, HU2|U], [HS1, HS2|S], C) :- % Ensure list args have at least 2 elements
    split([HU1, HU2|U], L, R),
    inversion(L, SL, C1),
    inversion(R, SR, C2),
    merge(SL, SR, [HS1, HS2|S], C3),
    C #= C1 + C2 + C3.

% Split list into left and right halves
split(List, Left, Right) :-
    split(List, List, Left, Right).
split(Es, [], [], Es).
split(Es, [_], [], Es).
split([E|Es], [_,_|T], [E|Ls], Right) :-
    split(Es, T, Ls, Right).

% merge( LS, RS, M )
merge([], RS, RS, 0).
merge(LS, [], LS, 0).
merge([L|LS], [R|RS], [L|T], C) :-
    L #=< R,
    merge(LS, [R|RS], T, C).
merge([L|LS], [R|RS], [R|T], C) :-
    L #> R, R #> 0 #<==> D, C #= C1+D,
    merge([L|LS], RS, T, C1).
```

You can ignore the second argument, which is the sorted list (just a side effect if all you want is the count of inversions).

Comment: Looks like many open CPs. Also `((L #> 0, R #> 0) ->` ... looks highly suspicious!

Comment: @false indeed, it exhibits CPs. It is a naive approach. I did update the `->` expression since it was a little excessive.

Comment: @false good suggestion. I wasn't very familiar with the `#<==>/2` operator.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another possibility to define the relation. First, `#</3` and `#\=/3` can be defined like so:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

bool_t(1,true).
bool_t(0,false).

#<(X,Y,Truth)  :- X #< Y #<==> B, bool_t(B,Truth).
#\=(X,Y,Truth)  :- X #\= Y #<==> B, bool_t(B,Truth).
```

Based on that, [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159) and [(',')/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36431808/6101159) a predicate `inv_t/3` can be defined, that yields true in the case of an inversion and false otherwise, according to the definition given by the OP:

```
inv_t(X,Y,T) :-
   if_(((Y#<X,Y#\=0),X#\=0),T=true,T=false).
```

And subsequently the actual relation can be described like so:

```
list_inversions(L,I) :-
   list_inversions_(L,I,0).

list_inversions_([],I,I).
list_inversions_([X|Xs],I,Acc0) :-
   list_x_invs_(Xs,X,I0,0),
   Acc1 #= Acc0+I0,
   list_inversions_(Xs,I,Acc1).

list_x_invs_([],_X,I,I).
list_x_invs_([Y|Ys],X,I,Acc0) :-
   if_(inv_t(X,Y),Acc1#=Acc0+1,Acc1#=Acc0),
   list_x_invs_(Ys,X,I,Acc1).
```

Thus the example queries given by the OP succeed deterministically:

```
?- list_inversions([1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7,8],N).
N = 0.

?- list_inversions([1,2,3,0,4,6,8,5,7],N).
N = 3.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using clpfd et automaton/8 we can write

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

inversions(Vs, N) :-
             Vs ins 0..sup,
             variables_signature(Vs, Sigs),
             automaton(Sigs, _, Sigs,
                       [source(s),sink(i),sink(s)],
                       [arc(s,0,s), arc(s,1,s,[C+1]), arc(s,1,i,[C+1]),
                        arc(i,0,i)],
                       [C], [0], [N]),
            labeling([ff],Vs).

variables_signature([], []).

variables_signature([V|Vs], Sigs) :-
            variables_signature_(Vs, V, Sigs1),
            variables_signature(Vs, Sigs2),
            append(Sigs1, Sigs2, Sigs).

variables_signature_([], _, []).

variables_signature_([0|Vs], Prev, Sigs) :-
      variables_signature_(Vs,Prev,Sigs).

variables_signature_([V|Vs], Prev, [S|Sigs]) :-
      V #\= 0,
      % Prev #=< V #<==> S #= 0,
      % modified after **false** remark 
      Prev #> V #<==> S,
      variables_signature_(Vs,Prev,Sigs).
```

examples :

```
?- inversions([1,2,3,0,4,6,8,5,7],N).
N = 3 ;
false.

?- inversions([1,2,3,0,4,5,6,7,8],N).
N = 0 ;
false.

?- inversions([0,2,X],1).
X = 1.
```

Comment: @false : tu es français ?

Comment: Rendons grâce à Alain Colmerauer !

Comment: C'est seulment maintenant que j'ai appris [la triste nouvelle](https://twitter.com/fbenhamou/status/864088974205349888)!

Comment: Ouch ! Je dois dire que je ne savais rien de ce décès : je plaisantais sur le fait que gràce à Alain Colmerauer, tu avais appris le français pour étudier son Prolog dans sa langue.

Answer (score 2):

in SWI-Prolog, with libraries [aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate#automaton/8) and [lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists):

```
inversions(L,N) :-
    aggregate_all(count, (nth1(P,L,X),nth1(Q,L,Y),X\=0,Y\=0,X>Y,P<Q), N).
```

both libraries are autoloaded, no need to explicitly include them.

If you want something more general, you can see the example in library([clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd)), under the automaton section, for some useful ideas. But I would try to rewrite your specification in simpler terms, using [element](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=element/3)/3  instead of nth1/3.

*edit*

after @false comment, I tried some variation on disequality operators, but none I've tried have been able to solve the problematic query. Then I tried again with the original idea, to put to good use element/3. Here is the result:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

inversions(L) :-
    L ins 0..8,
    element(P,L,X),
    element(Q,L,Y),
    X #\= 0, Y #\= 0, X #> Y, P #< Q,
    label([P,Q]).

inversions(L,N) :-
    aggregate(count, inversions(L), N) ; N = 0.
```

The last line `label([P,Q])` it's key to proper reification: now we can determine the X value.

```
?- inversions([0,2,X],1).
X = 1.
```

Comment: While `inversions([0,2,1],1).` succeeds its generalization `inversions([0,2,X],1).`  fails.

Comment: Why don't you fix your program? It's so easy like replacing `\=`  by `=\=` or putting `X>Y` first!

Comment: @false: thanks, I'll do... I had a short attempt to using clpfd:element/3, but it didn't worked

Comment: aggregate and clpfd do not flock together: `inversions([0,1,2],N).` now fails??

Comment: Also, please use a separate answer for a separate solution.

Comment: Now, `inversions([0,2,1],0)` succeeds and at the same time `inversions([0,2,1],1)` succeeds.